# Cassandra - Cqlengine - TTL Support

Tags: cassandra, ttl, cqlengine

I need to use TTL via cqlengine;
But there is no documentation about it.
Can someone help me about it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

TTL is supported.

```
In [13]: class Bacon(Model):       
   ....:     pk = Integer(primary_key=True)
   ....:     name = Text()
   ....:     

In [14]: sync_table(Bacon)

In [15]: Bacon.ttl(60).create(pk=1, name="delicious")
Out[15]: Bacon <pk=1>
```

See the following:

- https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html?highlight=ttl#cqlengine.query.QuerySet.ttl
- https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/models.html?highlight=ttl#cqlengine.models.Model.ttl

Answer (score 0):

Tried this, **But wont work**,

```
Bacon.create(pk=1, name="delicious").ttl(60)
```

**This will work perfectly**

```
Bacon.ttl(60).create(pk=1, name="delicious")
```

Use ttl() **before** create(), *works well in* **Django**